# Difference between drill layer, hole layer, and milling layer in Eagle

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, pcb-fabrication, eaglecad

What is the difference between the drill layer (44), the hole layer (45), and the milling layer (46) in Eagle PCB?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

- Drill layer (44) is used for pads (of through hole components) and vias.
- Hole layer (45) is used for mounting holes.
- Milling layer (46) is used for cutouts on the board, usually you can use the dimension layer (20) for that too.

Comment: why is drill used for pads?  Does that mean a pad with a hole in it?

Comment: @AlexisK Yes, when I mean pads I'm referring to through hole components.

Comment: Thanks for answer! I tested with layer 20 (dimensions) and everything is ok.

Comment: The reason for dividing these holes and dimensions on several layers are because a lot of the default scripts and ULP expect certain things to be on a specific layer.